# Gaussian Elimination with Partial Pivoting in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I've made a code of Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting in python using numpy.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[3, -13, 9, 3], [-6, 4, 1, -18], [6, -2, 2, 4], [12, -8, 6, 10]])
b = np.array([-19, -34, 16, 26])

def GaussEliminationPP(A, b):
    n = len(A)
    l = np.arange(n)
    s = np.zeros(n)
    for k in range(n) :
        amax = 0
        for i in range(k, n) :
            a = np.abs(A[l[i],k])
            if a > amax :
                amax = a
                j = i
        l[j], l[k] = l[k], l[j]
        for i in range(k+1, n) :
            xmult = A[l[i],k]/A[l[k],k]
            A[l[i],k] = xmult
            for j in range(k+1, n):
                A[l[i],j] -= xmult*A[l[k],j]
            b[l[i]] -= xmult*A[l[k],j]
        print(A, b)
            

GaussEliminationPP(A, b)
```

However, I've found out that it is having different value with the solution. And I don't have any clue where I was wrong. Can anyone help with this? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Could you add to your code a trial input it's result and what is the expected output.

Comment: Hi Seung, I can't tell you.  But I see that you have three layers of for statements.  I suggest breaking these out to functions and give them a name.  Then test each for very carefully to make sure that each sub-section is producing the desired output.

Comment: input is A and b in the code and as I didn't made a part for back substitution, output will be A = np.array([[0, -11, 15/2, 1/2], [0, 0, 4, -13], [0, 0, 0, 3/11], [12, -8, 6, 10]], b = np.array([-51/2, -21, 3/11, 26]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for the solution for your exercise (you can figure it yourself what the code does, that's the best way to study in my honest opinion):

```
    import numpy as np

def GaussEliminationPP(A, b):
    n = len(A)
    l = np.arange(n)
    s = np.zeros(n)
    for k in range(n):
        amax = 0
        for i in range(k, n):
            a = np.abs(A[l[i],k])
            if a > amax:
                amax = a
                j = i
        l[j], l[k] = l[k], l[j]
        for i in range(k+1, n):
            xmult = A[l[i],k]/A[l[k],k]
            A[l[i],k] = xmult
            for j in range(k+1, n):
                A[l[i],j] -= xmult*A[l[k],j]
            b[l[i]] -= xmult*b[l[k]]
    return A, b

A = np.array([[3, -13, 9, 3], [-6, 4, 1, -18], [6, -2, 2, 4], [12, -8, 6, 10]])
b = np.array([-19, -34, 16, 26])

A_new, b_new = GaussEliminationPP(A.copy(), b.copy())
print("A_new:")
print(A_new)
print("b_new:")
print(b_new)
```